# c# Regex Split Binary String

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string of binary digits in a specific way

Let's say this is my string `100011001110010101110`

I want to split the string at every **0** before a **1**

So the string above after split becomes

`1000 1100 11100 10 10 1110`

I used the Regex pattern `/(1+0+)/g` which splits the string properly, but it misses some groups.
Here is the c# code

```
Regex.Split(stringToSplit, @"(1+0+)");
```

Please what am i getting wrong.

**EDIT:** I failed to mention that I am certain a **1** will *always precede* a **0**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try looking *ahead* and *behind*, i.e. spilt on *zero-length* text with `0` *behind* the split and `1` *ahead* it

**Code:**

```
  string source = "100011001110010101110";

  var result = Regex.Split(source, "(?<=0)(?=1)");

  // Let's have a look
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1000
1100
11100
10
10
1110
```

**Edit:** Pattern `(?<=0)(?=1)` explanation:

```
(?<=0) - 0 should be behind the split
       - empty; split on epmty (zero-length) text
(?=1)  - 1 should be ahead of the split
```

So we have

```
1000 110011
   ^^^
   |||- 1 should be ahead of split
   ||--   split here
   |--- 0 should be behind the split
```

Comment: Nice! Can you please add more explanation about the pattern?

Comment: This works like a charm. No extra processing, you get the exact results you need.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your Regex Pattern returns several Matches as you can see [Here](https://regex101.com/r/sZIcZE/1).

You could retrieve the values using `.Matches()` instead.

```
Regex.Matches("100011001110010101110", "(1+0+)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: You will lose any leading zeros or trailing ones if present.

Comment: This works but it seems the Cast and Select increases execution time. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
var input = "100011001110010101110";
var results = Regex.Split(input, @"(1+0+)")
                        .Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n))
                        .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1000
1100
11100
10
10
1110
Press any key to continue . . .
```